# How to get crypto scheme UUID

Tags: android, encryption, android-mediaplayer, codec

> `MediaCrypto` class can be used in conjunction with `MediaCodec` to decode encrypted media data. Crypto schemes are assigned 16 byte UUIDs, the method `isCryptoSchemeSupported(UUID)` can be used to query if a given scheme is supported on the device.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCrypto.html

But what is crypto scheme UUID and where can I get it? Seems like I've missed it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The UUID is a plugin identifier, so the UUID depends on what the OEM provides

The snip code as bellow comes from `MediaDrmMockTest.java`(try to use mock plugin)

`static final UUID mockScheme = new UUID(0x0102030405060708L, 0x090a0b0c0d0e0f10L);`

Answer (score 1):

The [MediaDrm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html) docs say

> The app first constructs MediaExtractor and MediaCodec objects. It
>   accesses the DRM-scheme-identifying UUID, typically **from metadata in
>   the content**, and uses this UUID to construct an instance of a MediaDrm
>   object that is able to support the DRM scheme required by the content.

So the UUID is extracted from the content, if you already have that, but I'm not clear on how you extract it.

You can find some UUIDs in the [ExoPlayer source code](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/C.java):

```
final UUID COMMON_PSSH_UUID = new UUID(0x1077EFECC0B24D02L, 0xACE33C1E52E2FB4BL);
final UUID CLEARKEY_UUID = new UUID(0xE2719D58A985B3C9L, 0x781AB030AF78D30EL);
final UUID WIDEVINE_UUID = new UUID(0xEDEF8BA979D64ACEL, 0xA3C827DCD51D21EDL);
final UUID PLAYREADY_UUID = new UUID(0x9A04F07998404286L, 0xAB92E65BE0885F95L);
```

(Just concatenate the hex numbers to get the full UUID, without the dashes.)
The [DASH documentation](http://dashif.org/identifiers/protection/) has more UUIDs listed:

- Marlin:    `5E629AF5-38DA-4063-8977-97FFBD9902D4`
- Verimatrix VCAS: `9a27dd82-fde2-4725-8cbc-4234aa06ec09`
- Adobe Primetime: `F239E769-EFA3-4850-9C16-A903C6932EFB`

and others.

Comment: source code seems to be moved or package renamed with exoplayer2

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/b1000940eaec9e1202d9abf341a48a58b728053f/library/common/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/C.java#L38