# Is MediaCrypto suitable when decrypting on a different device to that used for encrypting?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I want to perform a one-time encryption of audio data which is then stored in assets (or SQLite database). The main application would therefore only need to perform decryption.

MediaCrypto requires a UUID but there [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369818/how-to-get-crypto-scheme-uuid) no UUID which can be used across all devices.  Therefore, is it not possible to use MediaCrypto for this purpose?

Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: You could make sure that all the parties involved in the process know the UUID, making the cipher an asymmetric one for added security if needed. Just my two cents.

Comment: But even if all parties know the UUID, what if someone uses a device that does not support that UUID? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCrypto.html#isCryptoSchemeSupported(java.util.UUID)

Comment: I'm writing from complete ignorance here, but maybe you could negotiate compatible UUIDs between devices in real time?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the encrypted data is in assets, so the UUID will already have been fixed.